# Execute a default action for MessageBox after an interval has elapsed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, c#-4.0

Let's say I have a custom message box used as follows

```
MyWindow.ShowDialog();
```

I need to `Close()`, `Hide()` or execute a handler say `Close_Click` after say 1 second if no user action occurs.

`Thread.Sleep()` and `Timer` approaches didn't help much.

**EDIT:**

I did this in the window constructor

```
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeOut);
    timer.Start();
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
      cmdClose_Click(null, null); //Attached to a button which normally does the job of closing the window.
    };
```

Comment: What problems did you have with a timer - that should have worked.

Comment: A timer will work. You need to make sure the timer starts before the call to ShowDialog()!

Comment: @ChrisF: I've added the relevant timer code that I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WPF, using a DispatcherTimer (System.Windows.Threading) on your custom message box will work. Just use the Tick event to call Close().

Comment: The question is tagged `WinForms`.

Comment: My bad. I'm using wpf but tagged winforms just to check if there are any approaches in winforms worth adopting.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar in the past. What I did was initialise a System.Threading.Timer that ticks periodically. On each tick if I can close the window (because some background operation has completed) I set the DialogResult and call Close (making sure to check InvokeRequired).

Answer (score 1):

One second sounds too short to me, but anyway.

Just add a `Timer` control to your custom message box form, enable it and set its `Intervall` to 1000. Then add a event for it's timer event and put the call to `Close()` inside.

Comment: Well, 2 seconds at the most, since I don't really want to force the user to click "OK" for success messages. Anyways, will try your suggestion.

Comment: @conqenator Your UI is wrong if you are showing a modal dialog and don't want the user to click a button to dismiss it. You want a balloon hint or status bar or something else.

Comment: I agree. But in this case I need to show that particular window as balloon tip.